# How to find device memory without using 'navigator.deviceMemory'

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications

I am trying to create a web app which helps with PC management and more, and one of the tabs include RAM usage. I want the web app to list the amount of ram the device currently has using javascript, e.g 16GB, 32Gb etc. I tried to use 'navigator.deviceMemory ([here is the API for people who want to see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/deviceMemory)), but it is capped at 8GB and overall not very accurate.

Is there another method I could use to determine the device RAM and display it?

Current code:

```js
function homePageStatsBarRandomTip() {
  var homePageStatsInnersBarPRamBottom = document.getElementById('homePageStatsInnersBarPRamBottom')

  homePageStatsInnersBarPRamBottom.innerHTML = navigator.deviceMemory + 'GB'
}
```

```css
.home-page-stats-inners-bar-p-ram-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translatey(-50%) line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<body onload="homePageStatsBarRandomTip()">
  <p class="home-page-stats-inners-bar-p-ram-bottom" id="homePageStatsInnersBarPRamBottom">blue</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I don’t absolutely know but suspect you cannot get such low level info via JS as you would like, any more than you can find the users directory structure. It would be quite intrusive..

Comment: Oh well. Thanks anyways, have a good day.